# is a set E=[0..1] U {10} both open and closed according to Rudin's definition?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[image: Here's definition from Rudin 1976]

Consider a set $E=[0..1] \cup \{10\}$

Note, that in (a) p may be equal to q.
So, according to (b) all points $[0..1]$ are limit.
Point 10 is isolated (c)
According to (b) every limit point of $E$ (which all are$[0..1]$) are points of $E$, so E is **closed**
All points of $E$ are interior(e), because all have neighborhood $\subset E$, even 10 itself, as $d(10,10) < r\ \forall r$
so by (f) $E$ is open.

What am I missing?

Comment: None of $0, 1, 10$ are interior points of $E$.

Comment: The complement: $(-\infty,0) \cup (1,10) \cup (10, \infty) $ is open. Hence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is closed, but not open.

---

**Not open**: There is no neighborhood of the point $10$ that is contained in the set. Similarly for $0$ and $1$.

Indeed, let $r > 0$. We consider the neighborhood $N_r(10) = (10 - r, 10+r)$. It should be clear that $(10-r,10+r)$ is never entirely contained in $[0,1] \cup \{10\}$.

A set is open if all its points are interior points, or equivalently, if for all points in the set, there is a neighborhood of that point that is contained entirely in the set.

In symbols: $A$ open $\iff \forall a \in A: \exists r > 0: N_r(a) \subseteq A$

Negating this: $A$ is not open $\iff \exists a \in A : \forall r > 0: N_r(a) \not\subseteq A $

and I proved the latter statement.

---

**Closed**: Your argument here is correct. Alternatively, you can notice that the (finite) union of closed sets is closed, and a singelton and a closed interval are standard closed sets in metric spaces.

---

**Addendum**: (1) It is possible that a set is both open and closed (= clopen). For example, in any metric space $X$, $X$ and $\emptyset$ are clopen. If these two sets are the only clopen sets in the metric space, the metric space is called *connected*, as Rudin will define at the end of that chapter.

(2) A commonly made mistake is saying that $A \subseteq X$ is not open is the same thing as $A$ is closed. It is true however that $A$ is open is the same thing as $X \setminus A$ is closed. Don't confuse these two statements!

Comment: Explain? $\space$

Comment: What should I explain more?

Comment: Well, it is clear that OP does not understand how to use the definition of open-ness using neighborhoods, and may not even understand neighborhoods (hence OP's attempt by stating $d(10,10)\lt r,\space\forall r$). Otherwise, nice answer!

Comment: I will edit this in.

Comment: @Frpzzd Do you think the answer is satisfactory now?

Comment: Yes! Nicely done. :)

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment :)

Comment: i should have been more attentive - your:
"A open $\Leftrightarrow \forall a \in A: \exists r > 0: N_r(a) \subseteq A$"
opened my eyes, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I asked original question ONLY with respect to set [0..1] U {10}, where no other points involved(before 0, between 1 and 10, and after 10. So in this case - such a set will be still both closed and open, as you stated about "any metric space X"

Comment: If you mean that the metric space you are working in is $[0,1] \cup \{10\}$, with the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to this set, then this set is clopen. My answer assumed you were working in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $r>0$ . So 0 ,1and 10 are not interior points. Your argument for proving the closeness of the set is correct.
I think you have  an older edition of the book. Check the recent edition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fault is that $0,1,$ and $10$ are not interior points of $E$ because there exists no neighborhood of any of those points that is contained in $E$.

You can show this by supposing that the open ball of radius $r$ about $10$ is in $E$, and then noticing that this would imply $10+\epsilon$ is in $E$ for sufficiently small $\epsilon\ne 0$, which is false. Similar arguments apply for $0$ and $1$, by considering $0-\epsilon$ or $1+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon\gt 0$.

[image]

Thus, $E$ is not open. Your argument that $E$ is closed contains no fault, so $E$ is closed.